# XPATH to select all not null childs plus a default value when not found

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Is there an XPATH to return all non-null `someChild` plus a default value for when the value on is not found?

```
<someFather>
    <someChild/>
    <someChild/>
    <someChild>some value</someChild>
    <someChild/>
    <someChild>some other value</someChild>
    <someChild/>
</someFather>
```

I would like to get:

```
""
""
some value
""
some other value
""
```

, or

```
"not-found"
"not-found"
some value
"not-found"
some other value
"not-found"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
/someFather/(someChild/string(), '')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/someFather/someChild/(text()/string(), "not-found")[1]
```

This is carefully written to avoid breaking the rule that the RHS of "/" cannot select a mixture of nodes and atomic values. In 3.0 you could use the "!" operator:

```
/someFather/someChild ! (text(), "not-found")[1]
```