# XPATH to return a default value when not found

Tags: xpath, xslt

I have a list of following items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ORDERS05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>006</QUALF>
            <ORGID>00</ORGID>
        </E1EDK14>
        <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>008</QUALF>
            <ORGID>NL01</ORGID>
        </E1EDK14>
        <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
            <QUALF>012</QUALF>
            <ORGID>ZOR</ORGID>
        </E1EDK14>
    </IDOC>
</ORDERS05>
```

I can use XSLT 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0, and would like XPATH to return a default value for when the value is not found or empty?

Tried in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html following XPATH expressions - if you remove xx the correct value is returned, otherwise "No Match!" is returned instead of "not-found"

XSLT 2.0 :

```
/ORDERS05/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF="008xx"]/ORGID/(text()/string(), "not-found")[1]
```

XSLT 3.0 :

```
/ORDERS05/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF="008xx"]/ORGID ! (text(), "not-found")[1]
```

```
/ORDERS05/IDOC/E1EDK14[QUALF="008xx"]/ORGID ! (node(), "not-found")[1]
```

Checked following [XPATH to select all not null childs plus a default value when not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157910/xpath-to-select-all-not-null-childs-plus-a-default-value-when-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selection of the `E1EDK14` element can fail, you need to add the alternative/default value at that level: `/ORDERS05/IDOC!(E1EDK14[QUALF="008xx"]!data(ORGID), "not-found")[1]`